# How to use a dijit /form/Select to change maps displayed on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I am trying to set up a webpage that will display maps and their associated legends when a user selects the map from a drop down list. I managed to get the page to have the format and design that I am looking for, and it even displayed the maps one at a time. However the issue that I am having is that I am trying to create an if loop that will run a specific formula based off of what the user selects in the drop down menu. The formula I used worked perfectly before I tried to use it in the loop, but now it doesnt seem to work at all and the only thing that will display on the page is the drop down menu itself. All of my formatting, tabs, and map data is gone. A friend of mine stated that I may need to use a 'destroy()' after each run of the function and then a 'create()' in order to reload the new data, but I am unsure how to go about this?  I feel like I am close to the answer but just can not seem to see where I am going wrong. I am still pretty new at all of this, so any help and explanation you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Lab 6</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/esri/css/esri.css">

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "dojo/parser",
      "dojo/ready",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
   "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
      "dojo/dom",
      "esri/map",
      "esri/urlUtils",
      "esri/arcgis/utils",
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (
      parser,
      ready,
      BorderContainer,
   TabContainer,
      ContentPane,
      dom,
      Map,
      urlUtils,
      arcgisUtils,
      Legend,
      Scalebar
    )
 function maplink(display){
  var maplink;
  if (display == "Chicago Youth"){
  maplink = ready(function () {

   parser.parse();

        
   arcgisUtils.createMap("c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8", "map").then(function (response) {
          
   dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
   dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

   var map = response.map;

          
   var scalebar = new Scalebar({
    map: map,
    scalebarUnit: "english"
   });

          
   var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
   var legendDijit = new Legend({
    map: map,
    layerInfos: legendLayers
   }, "legend");
   legendDijit.startup();
   });

   });

  });
  else if (display == "USA Median"){
  maplink = ready(function () {

   parser.parse();

        
   arcgisUtils.createMap("1e79439598494713b553f990a4040886", "map").then(function (response) {
          
   dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
   dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

   var map = response.map;

          
   var scalebar = new Scalebar({
    map: map,
    scalebarUnit: "english"
   });

          
   var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
   var legendDijit = new Legend({
    map: map,
    layerInfos: legendLayers
   }, "legend");
   legendDijit.startup();
   });

   });

  });
  else if (display == "Topo"){
  maplink = var topMap;
   require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(topMap) {
    map = new topMap("map", {
     basemap: "topo",
     center: [-95.71, 37.09],
     zoom: 5
    });
   });
  });
 
 return maplink;}
  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica";
    }

    #header {
      background-color: #E8E8E8;
      height: 65px;
      margin: 5px 5px;
    }

    #mainWindow {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #title {
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-size: 18pt;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    #subtitle {
      font-size: small;
      padding-left: 40px;
    }

    #leftPane {
      background-color: #E8E8E8;
      margin: 5px;
      width: 25%;
    }

    #map {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body class="claro">
<div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">
<div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
 <div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
    <div id="title"></div>
  </div>
   <div id="leftPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer"> 
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props= "title: 'Map Selection',selected:'true'">
    <select id="maplink" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
    <option value="Chicago Youth" selected >Chicago Youth Population</option>
    <option value="USA Median">USA Median Household Income</option>
    <option value="Topo">Topographic Map</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props= "title: 'Map Legend'">
   <div id="legend"></div> 
  </div>
    
 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rework your code, but I'm out of time for today. I just add what I have at the moment in answer, maybe it'll help you. 
One remark - you really need to destroy widgets, but there is a problem with legend - it destroys its reference node. But I don't have a workaround or solution for this right now.

In any case, take a look at what I can suggest you. Hope you'll get my idea. There are still a lot of things I'd implement in other way, but I just wanted to improve your code and not to start from the scratch.

```js
require([
      "dojo/parser",
      "dojo/ready",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
      "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
      "dojo/dom",
      "esri/map",
      "esri/urlUtils",
      "esri/arcgis/utils",
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
      "dijit/registry",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (
      parser,
      ready,
      BorderContainer,
      TabContainer,
      ContentPane,
      dom,
      Map,
      urlUtils,
      arcgisUtils,
      Legend,
      Scalebar,
      registry

    ) {

      parser.parse()

      ready(init)

      const maps = {
        'Chicago Youth': chikagoYouth,
        'USA Median': usaMedian,
        'Topo': topo

      }

      let legend
      let scalebar

      function createMap(response) {
        //document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = ``;
        if (legend) {
          legend.destroy()

        }
        if (scalebar) {
          scalebar.destroy()
        }
        
        dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
         //dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet; not found it

         var map = response.map;                  
         scalebar = new Scalebar({
           map: map,
           scalebarUnit: "english"
         });

              
         var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
         legend = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos: legendLayers
            }, "legend");
         legend.startup();
      }

      function chikagoYouth () {
        console.log('Chicago Youth')
        arcgisUtils.createMap("c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8", "map").then(createMap);
      }

      function usaMedian () {
        console.log('USA Median')
        arcgisUtils.createMap("1e79439598494713b553f990a4040886", "map").then(createMap);
      }

      function topo () {
        console.log('Topo')

        // require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(topMap) {
        //    let map = new topMap("map", {
        //      basemap: "topo",
        //      center: [-95.71, 37.09],
        //      zoom: 5
        //    });
        //  });
      }

      function init() {
        const mapSelect = registry.byId("maplink")
        mapSelect.on('change', loadMap)

      }

      function loadMap(value) {
        maps[value]()
      }
});
      
  </script>
```

I tested it, it works somehow, but only for fisrt load. So code still needs to be improved.

Good luck. If I have time, I'll edit my answer next days.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look over this for me! When I run your code its able to bring up my tabs, the correct layout, and show me the USA median household map, however I am still unable to get the maps to switch when I change the selection. Also I think you are right in regards to the legend, and I think that is where my friend told me I needed to do the create(), because the legend is not appearing at all for me.

Comment: @JJAbrams I know, that it doesn't change map if you've already selected one, but I posted it to give you some ideas how to reorganize your code to make it more understandable and readable. Regarding destroying and creating of legend/map - it's difficult to describe in comments.